# Which Statistical method should I use?

Tags: business-intelligence

I have been given a problem and need to find the best statistical method that would help. The problem is as follows:
A business has approx. 100,000 active customers who spend between £500 per annum and £200,000 per annum.  The smaller ones transact irregularly, once per year, the larger ones maybe once per week.  They are distributed across 15 different market sectors.
The business has started to decline, and whilst we have implemented a process for making offers to customers once they have closed their account, it is thought this would be much more effective if we could predict which customers are likely to close, and make offers to keep them before they close.

How would you go about determining which customers to make offers to?

Comment: [Please don't cross-post a question on multiple sites.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/217777/1352) Instead, flag it, request migration and wait for a little while. .Thank you.